# How to fix separate outputs in a recursive list

Tags: python, list, recursion

My function receives a list L and an integer n and returns a list containing the elements of L that are multiples of n, in the same order that they appear in L.

```py
def multiples(L,n):
    if len(L) == 0:
        return []
    if L[0]%n == 0:
        print(L[0])
    return multiples(L[1:],n)
```

For example:

```
multiples([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],2)
```

should return the list:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

and

```
multiples([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],5)
```

should return the list

```
[5, 10]
```

and

```
 multiples([3,6,9,12],5)
```

should return

```
 []
```

However, my output are the correct outputs, but separated by a single line and ending in `[]`.

Comment: It seems you are mixing up function `return` value and `print` output. Which do you want?

Comment: Why recursion? `print([i for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] if i % 5 == 0])` prints `[5, 10]`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it with recursion

```
def multiples(L,n):
    if len(L) == 0:
      return []
    else:
      if L[0]%n == 0:
        return [L[0]] + multiples(L[1:],n)
      else:
        return multiples(L[1:],n)
```

but as pointed out by others' comments, that may be overkill and a simple inline for loop will do it just fine

```
[i for i in L if i % n == 0]
```

Comment: That does work, however I was hoping for a solution without including to recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easier with list comprehension:

```
a = [i for i in range(11)] # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
n = 5
result = [x for x in a if x % n == 0] # [5, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to add an extra parameter, call it `arr`, which will hold all elements that are multiples of `n` and initialize it to be empty every time you call `multiples`:

```
def multiples(L,n,arr):
    if len(L) == 0:
        return arr
    if L[0] % n == 0:
        arr.append(L[0])
    return multiples(L[1:],n,arr)

print(multiples([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],2,[]))
print(multiples([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],5,[]))
print(multiples([3,6,9,12],5,[]))
```

This will produce:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
[5, 10]
[]
```